# STS 3.6.4 Gradle tooling not available?

Tags: spring-tool-suite, gradle-eclipse

I've just downloaded Spring Tool Suite 3.6.4 (201503100339, Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.2)) on Windows 8.  I'm attempting to import an existing Gradle project, but this option is not available within the import menu.

Playing a hunch that Gradle support may have been removed, I sought to install it from the Eclipse Marketplace.  But when I found "Gradle Integration for Eclipse (4.4) 3.6.4.RELEASE" the only option available was "uninstall", implying that it was already installed.

Is there something I need to do to "Activate" the Gradle tooling?

Answer (score 0):

The Gradle tooling is not installed by default if you download an STS distribution. You should be able to install it from the Eclipse marketplace or the dashboard.

If you are not sure whether this is installed or not, you can check that in the about dialog. There is an option to inspect the installation details.

Comment: Thanks Martin (nice to hear from you again).  The issue is that it looks like "Gradle Integration for Eclipse 4.4 3.6.4.RELEASE) tooling is installed in this new download of STS.  I can't install it from the Eclipse marketplace because it is already installed.  If I try to uninstall it, I get a message "The following solutions are not available: Gradle Integration for Eclipse(4.4) 3.6.4.RELEASE Proceed with the installation anyways?".  So I can't install it or uninstall it.

Comment: Just to confirm, I just deleted, downloaded, and unzipped STS 3.6.4 fresh.    As before, "Gradle Integration for Eclispe (4.4) 3.6.4.RELEASE" shows already installed, but doesn't show up in installation details.  Can't be installed or uninstalled in this limbo state.

Comment: Also, I've tried using the STS dashboard.  Here "Gradle Support" shows up as an available option.  But when installing I get "The following connectors are not available:  Gradle Support  Proceed with the installation anyways?"  The only entry in the log file is about mylyn discover (too large to fit here)

Comment: Hmmm... You are right, when going to the marketplace, the entry shows up as "uninstallable" only. This doesn't really mean that there is anything installed, but the behavior is clearly not as it should be.

Comment: However, installing this from the STS dashboard works for me. Maybe the "connector is not available" message comes from a network cache issue (sometimes the p2 component of Eclipse gets into a broken cache state). You can try to delete the p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache directory and start again. If the error persists, remove the STS update site from the list of the available update sites in the preferences, restart, and add it back. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

@Martin - I repeated my last steps, and this time "Gradle Support" installed without incident.  I have no clue what is different now, but the error about "connector not available" went away.  I now have Gradle support.  Thanks for your help! - k

Answer (score 0):

I checked the issue with the Marketplace again and it looks like a limitation of the Eclipse Marketplace client at the moment.

More details:
The Gradle IDE contains three features that should be installed. One of these features is the dashboard - which comes with STS by default. It looks like the marketplace client checks the already installed features and whenever it finds one of the features of the item to be installed in the existing installation, it enables the "uninstall" button. This seems to be the reason why the Gradle IDE entry from the Marketplace is listed as "uninstall".

I filed a bug for this against the Eclipse Marketplace. Lets see that happens. As a workaround, you should be able to install the Gradle tooling from the dashboard or the STS update site directly.

Comment: The Eclipse bug is: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=464112 - and it looks like it will be solved in Eclipse Mars. That is great!